# Connect Winform ComboBox validate with check box and submit button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, checkbox, combobox

Need help with project in C# on VS studio 2022.

This is in Winform.

in my groupbox (gpbHours) I have the worker enter their info with the combobox I set up. inside combobox text are numbers from 0 to 24. all combobox are name as (cbomon,cbotue…etc) with a check box that indicate if it was a off day underneath them, name as (chbmon, chbtue…etc)

Instruction asked to validate the result of user input when they click the submit button within the gorup, that if they put 0 for 1 of the days, the checkbox blew have to be checked. if check box is not check for the day and user picked 0 hours for the day it would show up as an error message.

also need to storage all the hours of user input from each combo box in order to calculate a pay sub later.

here is photo of my winform program layout.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiiAF.png)

here is my code, it is probably wrong. I'm new to the whole thing.'
private void btbsubmithour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
            if (hoursMon == 0 || chbmon.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't put any hours for Monday but did not check it as Holiday/Weekend/Vacation.", "Please check the box or change the hours.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            if (hoursTue == 0 || chbtue.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't put any hours for Tuesday but did not check it as Holiday/Weekend/Vacation.", "Please check the box or change the hours.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            if (hoursWed == 0 || chbwed.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't put any hours for Wednesday but did not check it as Holiday/Weekend/Vacation.", "Please check the box or change the hours.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            if (hoursThur == 0 || chbthur.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't put any hours for Thursday but did not check it as Holiday/Weekend/Vacation.", "Please check the box or change the hours.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            }
            if (hoursFri == 0 || chbfri.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't put any hours for Friday but did not check it as Holiday/Weekend/Vacation.", "Please check the box or change the hours.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            if (hoursSat == 0 || chbsat.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't put any hours for Saturday but did not check it as Holiday/Weekend/Vacation.", "Please check the box or change the hours.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            if (hoursSun == 0 || chbsun.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't put any hours for Sunday but did not check it as Holiday/Weekend/Vacation.", "Please check the box or change the hours.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        this.gpbPayrollinfo.Enabled = true;
        totalovertimepay = overtimesworked * (regularRate * 1.5);
        totalgrosspay = totalovertimepay + totalregularpay;
        totalregularpay = regularRate * regularhoursworked;

    }
```

I have try to use textbox but I got more confused with reading the value of them.